# Error with VS2022 - v143 - is_trivially_copyable_v

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

The following code does not compile with VS2022 / v143 in `/std::c++latest` mode.

```cpp
#include <string_view>

class XXX
{
public:
    std::string_view view;
};
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<XXX>);
```

It compiles fine with GCC, Clang and older versions of MSVC. Is this a known compiler bug? Or is it not a bug?

See: https://godbolt.org/z/Yvx5bGd9K

Comment: Should we worry about VS2012 preview?

Comment: Yes: Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 Preview (64-bit)
Version 17.0.0 Preview 3.1

I assume it is a bug...

Comment: [Regression bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/C-Compiler-is-overly-strict-regarding/101208?space=8&q=is_trivially_copyable_v), common MSVC++ issue.  You [already reported](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Error-with-VS2022---v143---is_trivially_/1510475?space=8&q=is_trivially_copyable_v) it for VS2022, that's where it belongs to get them to fix it again.

Comment: @HansPassant: yes.
But you agree - it is a bug, right?